using angular 17 generate device token for firebase web notification
I want to get the device token using firebase web notification. I have install @angular/fire is not supporting in angular cli 17. How to generate the device token when user is login.
I have installed
npm install @angular/fire firebase
Showing this error:TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/fire/messaging' or its corresponding type declarations.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private afMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {}
  title = 'gettoken';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.afMessaging.requestToken
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(token => {
        console.log('Permission granted! Save to the server!', token);
      }, error => {
        console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', error);
      });
  }
}

